# Javascript/Excel ActiveX object. Find exact match

Tags: javascript, excel, sharepoint, find, web-parts

So I am using a SharePoint web part (HTML Form Web Part) that I've built to query an excel file that is hosted on our Sharepoint site. I wrote javascript to create an Excel ActiveX object, and I can search the worksheet just fine.

However, I need to have it search for an exact match (the whole cell) not just part. I know the code that I need, I just can't make it work. I need to find out how to create the correct object type for the "xlWhole" argument of the "Find()" function.

The line of code I am having trouble with is commented out, because that didn't work. Any insight? I've seen the Range.Find method, but I just can't make it work.

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

var wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("workbook path");
var ws = wb.Worksheets("worksheet name");
var ws = wb.ActiveSheet;
//var cell = ws.Cells.Find(str,excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole);
var cell = ws.Cells.Find(str);
foundRow = cell.Row;
```

Comment: All you need to do is pass the value of the constant `xlWhole` (which is 1) - you can find this in the Excel vBA Object Browser.

Comment: Try `ws.Cells.Find(str,,,1)`

Comment: ws.Cells.Find(str,,,1) gives me a syntax error, and ws.Cells.Find(str,0,0,1) gives me a type mismatch. This should work in JavaScript, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
function searchExcel()
{
    var excel =new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    excel.visible=true;

    var wb = excel.workbooks.open("D:\\Analysis\\tmp\\Book1.xlsx");
    var ws = wb.sheets(1);

    var str="Value1";

    // .Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, 
    //                                 MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
    var cell = ws.Cells.Find(str,ws.Cells(1),-4163,1)

    alert(cell?cell.Row:(str+" not found"));

    excel.quit();
}
```

I guess you cannot skip over parameters when using COM from js (but you can leave them off the end).

Comment: Bingo. That did it. Where did you find the information on the constants for the Find() function?

Comment: In Excel go to the VB editor and hit `F2` to bring up the Object Browser window: you can enter the constant names to see their values. Or in the Immediate/Debug window just type (eg) `? xlWhole`.  The list of parameters is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx